# Facebook App vs Facebook Connect App

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm starting on an application which will integrate with Facebook. I'm new to Facebook development and would like to understand the difference between a Facebook app (canvas based) and a web application based on Facebook Connect. Are there technical or functional limitations in a Facebook Connect based application, which can otherwise be achieved in a Facebook App. I'm tending towards a Facebook Connect application by default since there are no restrictions on the UI (eg the dimensions etc), but am curious as to why people write Facebook apps.

Comment: Where did you get these "terminologies"? any FB documentation page to refer to?

Comment: Facebook App = A canvas app embedded in Facebook.com. Facebook Connect based Web App = A web app using Facebook Connect.

Comment: So based on the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/), you want to compare the "Websites" to "Apps on Facebook.com"?

Comment: Yes. Are there particular use cases where writing Apps is better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration [Facebook app or social plugins in your Website](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) can't be compared to [Apps on Facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/). You first need to realize the purpose of your project.

In short, if your project/product has more to do with social media and user interactions you develop it as a Facebook app on Facebook.com like [VarmVile](http://www.facebook.com/FarmVille).

But if you have a standalone website and you just need to enhance it and add some "social love" to it, then you build your website and then think of best strategies to implement Facebook Apps, social plugins within it. Example for this can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/showcase/).

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Connect allows an external site to interface with Facebook for login and whatnot.  A Facebook App is an app that is viewed and used inside Facebook itself.

Comment: I understand the difference. I just don't get the advantage of embedding an app inside Facebook, unless its something very small.

Comment: The advantage of embedding it is that more people will share and use a fully embedded Facebook application.  Comparatively few people have the interest and wherewithal to actually go to another site and authenticate with their Facebook credentials.

Answer (score 0):

web application based on Facebook Connect - website using facebook connect to share,comment etc from web page. you can found example sites on this link http://mashable.com/2009/01/12/facebook-connect-implementations/

facebook App(canvas based) - website inside facebook iframe/canvas e.g. any application on facebook